# Commit a String with JGit

Tags: java, jgit

A JGit-beginner-question:

I use JGit to read a file (BLOB) from a repository and manipulate its content. After that, I want to write the new content with the same filename back to the repository as a new commit. But how can I commit the new content with JGit?

My pseudo-code:

```
String gitUrl = "path/to/repository/.git";
Repository repository = new FileRepository(gitUrl);
String filename = "test/seppl.txt";
blobId = getIdOf(filename);
ObjectLoader object = repository.open(blobId, Constants.OBJ_BLOB);
ObjectStream is = object.openStream();
String newContent = processStream(is);
// How to commit the newContent in filename?
```

Do I have to write the `newContent` into a file and commit this file with the [AddCommand](http://jgit.info/javadoc/org/eclipse/jgit/api/AddCommand.html) and [CommitCommand](http://jgit.info/javadoc/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CommitCommand.html)? Or can I write the String "on-the-fly" into the repository under the same filename?

Is there anywhere in the web an example how to make a commit with JGit?

Comment: As for an example of a CommitCommand, I suggest you have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861881/jgit-cannot-find-a-tutorial-or-simple-example/10311069#10311069).

Comment: I also recommend to use the porcelain API (i.e. `AddCommand`, `CommitCommand`) as suggested in the answers, but if you really want to commit _on the fly_ you may find this article useful:: http://www.codeaffine.com/2014/10/20/git-internals/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there is no other way to commit any data than using the CommitCommand (except merging or such operations that are very specific).

So, yeah, you should make any change in your file and then add it and commit it (using the AddCommand and CommitCommand from the API).

Comment: Ok, I will try this, as it seems to be the easiest way and maybe optimize it later.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, of course you can do what you want, but just not using Add/Commit as they are part of the **high-level** [Porcelein API](http://wiki.eclipse.org/JGit/User_Guide#Porcelain_API) which is just a convenience API built ***on top*** of the low level API. Thus they just implement the most common use cases.

What you need to do is to look at the implementation of the [AddCommand](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/AddCommand.java#L125) and [CommitCommand](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CommitCommand.java#L149) to see how to use the lower-level API to create BLOB objects and then tree objects and than commit objects.

I'd second the recommendation that you thoroughly [read chapter 9 of the Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals) so that you properly understand how Git works on a low level.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look into using Blob's in Git. This technique is used to store the public PGP key's when signing Tags. It looks like the *content* you want still has to be put into a file, but it can be a temp file. The file won't exist in the main directory when someone does a pull. It'll be an entry in the tree as a blob.

http://book.git-scm.com/7_raw_git.html

The `-w` tells it to write the entry along with returning the hash.

```
git hash-object -w myfile.txt
6ff87c4664981e4397625791c8ea3bbb5f2279a3
```

*Update*

I skimmed through this entry on my phone and thus was less then attentive to the detail you provided. Yes you'd need to write the string to a file, but no you shouldn't have to add it like a normal file. I would suspect that JGit has the ability to do `hash-object`. It looks like you already has some code to deal with a BLOB entry. Perhaps there is a higher level call for hash-object in which you don't deal with the BLOB directly.

Considering everything in Git relies on hashes of content, I would say that, even if you did find a way to write the string directly you shouldn't. You should recommit the object with the same filename such that you get a new hash and updated entry.

Comment: Hm, very interesting, thanks. But I will stay with the the Add/CommitCommand because it's now the easiest one.